# Does this sentence require a comma after published?

Tags: punctuation

Random House has published *America, a story*, a new book about...

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you think it needs one?

Comment: No, it doesn't and even underneath why you think it needs one, where did you read that or any sentence like it, please?

*… a story, a new book about…*  is wholly unlikely except as an artificial classroom construct.

Comment: It is hypothetical, but if the book was called 'America, a story', shown in italics above, then surely I could follow it with 'a new book about...'?

Comment: I'm so sorry I missed that…

No, if I'd noticed the italics, it would have been doubly obvious that comma is not only not necessary, but clearly undesirable. Any title in italics is wholly parenthetical; so much so, you could almost omit the title itself and drop back to *Random House has published a new book about...*

Either way, it's all but certain *America, a Story* needs that capital *S*, which partly excuses my missing it…